# Is there a way to catch event, when user shares the Power App / Power Flow?

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, power-platform

I am trying my best to govern Power Platform in a tenant, and I would be thrilled to find a way to find a trigger, which would push always when an app or Power automate flow in an environment is shared with someone.

I am aware of CoE Starter kit and ways of inspecting the users which the app was shared with.

Now I am looking for ways to automate this and getting notification always when user is sharing the resources with somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no trigger available for your requirements to get notified when user shares the Power App / Power Automate flow with other users.

You can get the list of users having access to Power Apps or Power Automate using default actions available in below connectors or using PowerShell:

1. [Power Automate Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/connectors/flowmanagement/)
2. [Power Apps for Admins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/connectors/powerappsforadmins/)
3. [Power Apps for Makers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/connectors/powerappsforappmakers/)
4. [PowerShell Cmdlets Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powerapps.administration.powershell/)